# 'family' argument is not a valid family object for poisson regression with offset?

Tags: r, poisson

This is my line of code:

> driver<-glm(ncrash~offset(log(expos))+adol+DE,family = poisson,data=drive)

and this is the error:

Error: 'family' argument seems not to be a valid family object

I'm really not sure what this error means. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: did you name anything as poisson in your environment?? can you do rm(poisson) and run it again

Comment: Another option to avoid naming conflicts would be `family = stats::poisson`

Comment: Did you try running without the offset? I only ask because I'm guessing it's completely unrelated but I don't think you did even that much debugging yet.